# Long Object in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a large CSV that is a result of a python script I wrote.  Each row contains a list of entries, that when I wrote were strings or ints.  Please note that the files from my script are sometimes created on either linux or windows platform (which might be the problem, hence the mention.  I'm new at multi-platform python, so please forgive me).

Now, I'm trying to read the .csv in but some of the ints come in as long objects, according to type(whatiwant).  I've tried everything I and my google fu can think of to convert these objects to int (int(), str(). replace for " ", "L", and "/r", "/n").  Nevertheless, when I test the list via for loop and type(), output says some things are still long objects.

What am I missing here?  I tried looking for background info on long objects but couldn't find anything useful, hence the post.

I'm new at all this, so again, please forgive my ignorance.

When it rains, it pours.  Sorry for screwing up the edit rofl:

I'm reading in the values like this (which are writte in rows, as a list containing values that are ints and strings):

```
Input  = [["header"|"subheader"], [15662466|2831811638], 
        [5662466|27044023]...]
data = []
people_list = []
for entry in input:
    data.append(entry)
for row in data:
    holder = row.split("|")
    person = str(holder([1])
    people_list.append(person.replace.("\r", "").replace("\n","").replace("L", "")
people_list.pop(0)
for person in people_list:
    strperson = str(person)
    intperson = int(strperson)
    print intperson
    print type(intperson)
```

output:

```
2831811683
<type 'long'>
27044023
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: a long on windows is not the same as a long on unix,what you see as an int on python2 in unix can be a long on windows, either way it is not really a problem.

Comment: You can ignore the difference between `int` and `long` in nearly every case. Use them interchangeably. In Python3, there really IS no difference.

Comment: Without further code, we can't go any further. Your question is "How do you convert a `long` to an `int`," to which the answer is "You don't." The question it seems like you SHOULD ask is instead "Why can't I use a `long` in *XYZ* API."

Comment: can you post whatever you get?

Comment: First of all, make sure you use the csv module to parse your CSV, it will save you a lot of hassle, especially handling the line endings. In Python 2, an int is a C long, and a long is like BigInterger in Java, it's a type that can hold any size of integer (it allocates memory if it's too big)

Comment: You can convert a long to an int with `i = int(l)`, but if the value is too big, it will produce a long whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

They are being treated as longs. Python as two number types: ints, which have a maximum and minimum value, and longs, which are unbounded. It's not really a problem if the numerical data is a long instead of an int.

Answer (score 0):

A `long` is a datatype that is just `long`er than an int.

More formally `long` is the datatype used when integers would have caused an integer overflow, so anything more than `sys.maxint` automatically converts your int to a `long`.

Docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric

Note that in Python 3 there is no significance between the two, as Python3 unifies the two types.

Comment: I'm in python 2.7 and I need these values intact to throw at an API.  Is there anyway to convert?  Or must I read them in with Python 3.0?

Comment: @JoshUsre The API should be able to handle it (assuming that it's also python) as `long` accepts the same operations as `int`s

Comment: It will only accept int objects according to the error message, which really confuses me because if I make a variable with the same value that's not a string, it doesn't seem to have a problem.

Comment: I suspect your API is getting the value with a trailing "L" as it's a long and it only accepts digits. You could just convert it yourself.

Comment: agreed with @gecko don't pass it a string, pass it an `int` (or a `long`)